# Mint wont boot. Boots to built-in shell (ash)

Tags: boot, linux-mint

My Linux isnt as strong as my Windows, so I thought Id ask here before I go poking around any making things worse.

I have two hard drives in my computer. The first drive has a Windows 10 install and is the default boot option in BIOS. On the second drive, I have a Linux Mint 18.3 install. Mint's bootloader is on the second drive. I boot to it by selecting a boot device during boot up. So the two OSs are completely separate. I do run VirtualBox in Windows and boot Mint directly from the second hard disk as a VM.

This is where my problem started. I was uninstalling software on Windows and needed to reboot. I started a reboot and when Windows wasnt shutting down I realized that Mint was still running. However, VirtualBox is smart and it was saving the state of Mint. After that finished, the machine rebooted. However, I was distracted and booted directly into Mint, via the selecting the Mint disk. I would get the Mint logo and "dots," but it wont boot completely. Obviously Mint is not booting, as it was not properly shutdown. However, I dont know how to fix this.  Whether I boot directly from hard disk, or start it as a VM, I get this shell:

[image]

This is a shell, with a blinking cursor after `(initramfs)`. I have never seen this before, and typing "help" isnt helpful.

Any ideas as to what I should do?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT that was it.  I had to change `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y` to `fsck /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root -y`, but it worked.  Make that an answer, and Ill mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the ["Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox) post you should try running the command `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y` or similar to check and repair the file system.

If it finds errors it'll go through and fix them and then upon reboot it'll boot normally again.

---

### Further Resources

- [fsck](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-fsck/)